# What's the proper way to build a multi-arch Debian package?

Tags: linux, build, debian, deb

Every time I try to build `bluez` I get the error:

```
dh_install: libbluetooth3 missing files (usr/lib/*/libbluetooth.so.3), aborting
```

Looking in my own path I see that the currently installed version of the library is located at:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbluetooth.so.3
```

But the build script (`fakeroot debian/rules binary`) keeps putting the output into `usr/lib/libbluetooth.so.3`.

Answer (score 0):

To specify the correct folder you need to declare the environment variable `DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH` and use the `binary-arch` target (though `binary` may suffice as documentation suggests `binary` calls both `binary-arch` and `binary-indep`):

```
DEB_HOST_MULTIARCH=x86_64-linux-gnu debian/rules binary-arch
```

The value was chosen based off of the current install path of `libbluetooth.so.3` (/usr/lib/**x86_64-linux-gnu**/libbluetooth.so.3) and could possibly change if the Debian distribution you're running places 64bit binaries elsewhere.